# Edge Dev tools Win 11: Inspect not working on

Tags: android, windows, microsoft-edge, windows-11, edge-devtools

Please tell me why I can't click and view the app on Edge Devtools. i.e. I can't click the `inspect` link and not open it.

[image]

Win 11 : Version 119.0.2151.44 (Official build) (64-bit)

Android Edge Mobile version(latest): 118.0.2088.66

Answer (score 1):

I have also reproduced this issue on Microsoft Edge Stable 119, where "inspect" does not work. So I suggest you send feedback to Edge Dev Team by **Alt+Shift+I**.

However, this feature works well if you use **Microsoft Edge Dev 120**. As a workaround, you can switch to Edge Dev (**on your Windows 11**) for further tests. You can also expect this issue to be fixed in the near future since version 120 has no such issue.

Comment: Sure, We're lucky hence we have Chrome too :D